# How do I change the air to a solid and the solid to air? essentially I want to have the effect of filling it up with water and solidifying the water?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

I need to fill up the space inside of this object, and I need to replace the current object that has solidified areas with air. Thanks

Comment: I _think_ I understand what you mean.. by 'change to air'.. do you mean 'make completely transparent' ?

Comment: sort of. I would like to change the light grey(solid) parts of the object to air and fill the inside to make the inside solid. Essentially I need to fill up the inside because I want to cut that shape out of a different object. It's important that the solution is not just for show, because I am going to 3D print it.

Comment: .. so you don't need a fluid simulation, or anything, just to get the negative space inside..